# Replacing an entire matrix block (arbitrary size) in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I need to replace the last `n+2` rows of a matrix with

```
myeye = eye(n+2, (n+1)^2);
```

Is there anyway to do this besides doing it element wise?

Essentially, I'd like to do something like this

```
myMatrix((n+1)^2-(n+1):end) = myeye; %the index is just the last n+2 rows
```

Of course that's not legal, but that's what I'd like to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
 myMatrix((end - size(myeye, 1) + 1):end, :) = myeye(:, 1:size(myMatrix, 2))
```

Pay attention to the use of the keyword `end` to obtain the last row index.

Also note that since `myeye` is basically an n-by-n unity matrix concatenated horizontally with a zeros matrix, you can achieve the same effect in a simpler way:

```
 myMatrix((end - n - 1):end, :) = eye(n + 2, size(myMatrix, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a=randi(10,[30 7]);
aNew=a;
n=1;
if (n+1)^2>=size(aNew,2)
   nRows=size(aNew,2);
else
   nRows=(n+1)^2;
end
aNew(size(a,1)-(n+1):end,1:nRows)=eye(n+2, (n+1)^2); %This is where you actually replace a block.
```